# Trouble with using R Kernel using conda and Jupyter

Tags: r, bash, ipython, jupyter, conda

I installed R essentials using this blog post

http://continuum.io/blog/conda-jupyter-irkernel

create a new environment just for “R essentials”:

```
conda create -n my-r-env -c r r-essentials
```

Bash

```
ipython notebook
```

But when I try and create a new notebook using R Kernel

I get this error

```
An error occurred while creating a new notebook.
Unexpected error while saving file: Untitled5.ipynb [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ajay/.ipython/profile_default/security/notebook_secret'
```

How can i start using R from within Jupyter (Ipython)? Apologize for the very basic question

[image]

This is what I get if I type id in terminal

```
ajay@Inspiron-3542:~$ id
uid=1000(ajay) gid=1000(ajay) groups=1000(ajay),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),109(lpadmin),124(sambashare)
```

Comment: You need to have the permissions to write to `/home/ajay/.ipython/profile_default/security/notebook_secret`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are on a linux host

Start a terminal in jupyter (from home page new->terminal)

in terminal type :
id

If the information you get do not match your id you need to start jupyter with NB_UID=your uuid option

Are you running this from a docker container?

Comment: You need to type both id in the jupyter console ( within chrome browser ) and in an OS shell to see if from jupyter you are seen as a diffrent id

Comment: What should be done if running on a Docker container?